# Local systems defined by higher homotopy groups

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I should mention I have very little background in algebraic topology and don't really know much about homotopy groups besides the definition.

I am aware that for a topological space $X$ and a point $x \in X$ the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x)$ acts on all homotopy groups $\pi_n(X,x)$. In particular, this means the $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space $\mathbf{Q} \otimes_\mathbf{Z}\pi_n(X,x)$ is endowed with a linear action by $\pi_1(X,x)$ and hence defines a local system of $\mathbf{Q}$-vector spaces on $X$. If $X$ is a (complex) manifold or something and one can appeal to tools akin to the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence and other interpretations of these objects, can one describe these explicitly? Are they 'tautological' local systems in some sense... ? Can anything be said about the *family* of local systems $(\mathbf{Q}\otimes_\mathbf{Z}\pi_n(X,x))_{n \geq 2}$ and can these be recognised as something else?

I'm not sure my question makes much sense and I was just trying to satiate a curiosity :) Any words of wisdom are appreciated and thank you very much! :D

Edit: [moved to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444040/local-systems-arising-from-higher-rational-homotopy-groups)

Comment: Good question! I don’t actually know but my guess is that there’s no general answer. For example, knowing these local systems for a high dimensional sphere is equivalent to knowing the ranks of its homotopy groups. If you don’t get a good answer here it may be worth asking again on MO

Comment: @Exitpath thank you very much!! :) I'm slightly scared of trespassing the stack exchange boundaries since I've accidentally done so before hahah do I just delete this question and copy-paste it on MO? :P sorry for the dumb question

Comment: Usually it’s best to leave the question here but add a link to your MO post and say it has been cross-posted